# Filter duplicate values in string Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, duplicates

When mentioning users, if I mention one user more than once, I get string like:

```
"@[Firstname Lastname](4652) @[Firstname Lastname](4652) @[Firstname Lastname](4652)"
```

I tried to filter so the payload contains only one of those values. (`@[Firstname Lastname](4652)`) The first problem I occured is the space is optional, so I couldn't split the array (I created an array out of string) by space. If I split it with @, it doesn't send the @ in the payload.
I assume I should create some kind of regex which will compare text between '@' and last ')', based on uses's ID which is in the brackets. But I was unable to create one.
Another issue is that users can write text as well, not just mention users, so it could look like:

```
"bla bla @[Firstname Lastname](4652) bla bla @[Firstname Lastname](4652) bla bla"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the entire string using split(" ")

```
const string = "bla bla @[Firstname Lastname](4652) bla bla @[Firstname 
Lastname](4652) bla bla";

const stringArr = string.split(" "); //Split the string into array of strings

let users = [];
const userPattern = /@[a-z]*)/i; //Begins with `@` and ends with `)`    

stringArr.forEach((item) => {
   if(userPattern.test(item)
   {
      users.append(item);
   }
});

users = unique(users);
```

**Function to remove duplicates**

```
function unique(a) {
    var seen = {};
    var out = [];
    var len = a.length;
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var item = a[i];
         if(seen[item] !== 1) {
               seen[item] = 1;
               out[j++] = item; //Adding unique arrays to this array
         }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this regex is not good since it throws me an error whenever i try to edit the value. 

Error: Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression: /@[a-z]*)/: Unmatched ')

I even tried this:

const regex = new RegExp(`/@[a-z]*)/i`);

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //@[a-z]*)/i/: Unmatched ')'

Answer (score 0):

I think "@" is the safest way to split the string because that ensures only one user id is present in each element. Since "@" is always followed by "[", it can be added back using:

```
dataPart.replace("[", "@[");
```

That issue resolved, it becomes a case of keeping track of id numbers as you add them to a new 'payload' array or string.

In the implementation suggested in my snippet, the data is split at "@" into an array. The array is then looped though using `forEach`. Each element is examined for the presence of an Id number - located by the presence of "(". New Ids are added to a `seen` array which can be checked during subsequent loops to see if the id has been seen before. If the Id is unique, the element is transferred to the payload (and the id added to `seen`).

The limitations are that the id must be the only part enclosed in brackets "()", and if there is extra text in subsequent repeats of a given id, it will be lost (but text at the beginning will persist.

```js
let atList = "hello @[Firstname Lastname](4652) @[Firstname Lastname](4652)   @[Firstname Lastname](2352) @[Firstname Lastname](4652) @[Firstname Lastname](1637)";

const parts = atList.split("@");
const payload = [];
const seen = [];

 parts.forEach(element => {
 
   currentId = element.slice(element.indexOf("(")+1,element.indexOf(")"));
   
   if (seen.indexOf(currentId) == -1 && element.length > 0) {
   
     payload.push(element.replace("[", "@["));
     seen.push(currentId);
   } 
   
 }); 
 
 payloadString = payload.join("");
 console.log(payloadString);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just split the string into an array at the end of each username, which is the `)` character. Remove all characters before the `@` symbol, then add the new array element to a second array if it is not already present.

EDIT: Made code executable

```js
function getUsernames(string) {
  var array = [] // Second Empty Array
  for (var s of string.split(")")) { // For Loop through first 'split' array
        if (!array.includes(s.substring(s.indexOf("@"))+")") && s.includes("@")) array.push(s.substring(s.indexOf("@"))+")") // If the second array doesn't have the split element, add it
  }
  return(array)
}
console.log(getUsernames("@[Firstname Lastname](4652) @[Firstname Lastname](4652) @[Firstname Lastname](4652)")) // Print out your refined array of usernames
console.log(getUsernames("@[Firstname Lastname](0001) abcd @[Firstname Lastname](0002) 1234 @[Firstname Lastname](0003) <?/[}")) // Print out your refined array of usernames
```